# Authenticate / open a file over https in java

Tags: java, https, httpclient

Let's say I want to connect to https://www.code.com/secure/test.xml and pull all the data.  Before allowing me to pull said data it prompts me for my credentials.

How can I handle this using java?  I've googled around and landed at the Appache httpClient but can't find ANYTHING on https with it.

Comment: Have you tried? It appears to use SSLSocketFactory under the hood.

Comment: What kind of authentication is used? HTTP Basic/Digest? Client certificates? What's specific about HTTPS here?

Comment: Bruno:  The auth is http Basic.   If you'd like to take a crack at the answer I'd love to see what you have in mind.  "your client must support HTTP Basic Authentication over SSL. If you do not have credentials, you can apply for access by visiting" Is the posted description of the API, so I'm not really 100%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick search showed:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/net/http-auth.html

So you probably have to set the default Authenticator:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Authenticator.html#setDefault%28java.net.Authenticator%29